# Why Is my code being ignored?

Tags: sql, sql-like

When I execute the only thing that is working is the Zipcodes. It is not giving me a service date greater than 08/01/16 or my Billing Providers. I am not sure why.

```
SELECT Name, BirthDate, Address1, Address2, City, StateProvince, ZipCode, BillingProviderID, ServiceDate, ChargeCatID
FROM dbo.PbrChargeTransactions
WHERE ChargeCatID = 'EM'
AND ServiceDate >= '08/01/16'
AND BillingProviderID IN ('AAD.FD','DSD.DFD','ASDF.DD')
AND ZipCode Like '68730%'
OR ZipCode Like '68792%'
OR ZipCode Like '68739%'
OR ZipCode Like '68718%'
OR ZipCode Like '57069%'
OR ZipCode Like '57031%'
OR ZipCode Like '57078%'
OR ZipCode Like '57066%'
OR ZipCode Like '57063%'
OR ZipCode Like '57037%'
OR ZipCode Like '57073%'
OR ZipCode Like '57029%'
OR ZipCode Like '57070%'
ORDER BY Name
```

Comment: You need some parentheses: right now, you're getting (ChargeCatID = 'EM' AND ServiceDate >= '08/01/16' AND BillignProviderID IN (...) AND ZipCode Like '68730%') OR (ZipCode Like '68792%') OR (ZipCode Like ...). Obviously, that's not what you're after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operator precedence: "And" binds more tightly than "or". That is, only the first zip-code comparison is evaluated with the rest of your "and" conditions. The rest are 'OR's and if they match, you get the record.

Try this:

```
SELECT Name, BirthDate, Address1, Address2, City, StateProvince, ZipCode,     BillingProviderID, ServiceDate, ChargeCatID
FROM dbo.PbrChargeTransactions
WHERE ChargeCatID = 'EM'
AND ServiceDate >= '08/01/16'
AND BillingProviderID IN ('AAD.FD','DSD.DFD','ASDF.DD')
AND (ZipCode Like '68730%'
OR ZipCode Like '68792%'
OR ZipCode Like '68739%'
OR ZipCode Like '68718%'
OR ZipCode Like '57069%'
OR ZipCode Like '57031%'
OR ZipCode Like '57078%'
OR ZipCode Like '57066%'
OR ZipCode Like '57063%'
OR ZipCode Like '57037%'
OR ZipCode Like '57073%'
OR ZipCode Like '57029%'
OR ZipCode Like '57070%'
)
ORDER BY Name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `(...)` as n8wrl shows or the following, which I think will be faster.

```
SELECT Name, BirthDate, Address1, Address2, City, StateProvince, ZipCode, BillingProviderID, ServiceDate, ChargeCatID
FROM dbo.PbrChargeTransactions
WHERE ChargeCatID = 'EM'
AND ServiceDate >= '08/01/16'
AND BillingProviderID IN ('AAD.FD','DSD.DFD','ASDF.DD')
AND LEFT(ZipCode,5) in ('68730','68792','68739','68718','57069','57031', '57078','57066','57063','57037','57073','57029','57070')
ORDER BY Name
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be because you missed some parenthesis. Please be aware of the [precedence of operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190276.aspx)

If you write

```
A AND B AND zip1 OR zip2 OR zip3
```

this is equals to

```
((A AND B) AND zip1) OR zip2 OR zip3
```

I think you intended to write

```
A AND B AND (zip1 OR zip2 OR zip3)
```

where A, B, zip1,...  are boolean conditions like       `zip LIKE '12345%'`